# How to convert columns to rows in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, pivot

I have a table in this form (this is just a partial view, the table contains more than 100 columns).

```
 env_id    property_TYPE   property_name
  1         user            user1
  1         host            host1
  99        user            user2
  99        host            host2
  1         FS              fs1
```

for a single env_id, I have different kinds of property types.
I want these details to be converted into columns and take the following shape:

```
Env_id     user    host
 1          user1   host1
 99         user2   host2
```

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of **decode** function I am able to achieve my requirement.

**pivot**  is also another solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it through `PIVOT`, the below is an example

```
Select * from (
   select property_name, env_id
   from table t
)
pivot 
(
   count(property_TYPE)
   for property_TYPE in ('USER','HOST')
)
order by env_id
/
```

Comment: property_type is not identifier and if i add use below modified code
Select * from (
   select property_name, env_id,property_TYPE
   from table t
)
pivot 
(
   count(property_TYPE)
   for property_TYPE in ('USER','HOST')
)
order by env_id
/

under user and host column i am getting numbers .

Comment: in place of count if I use min or max  then i got my desired output format but all the rows are not coming out of 3000 only 90 rows are coming.

Comment: we cannot use pivot function as this work on aggregate functions only due to this i am not getting my desired output .